# Dice probability with dependent conditions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Greeting,

I am curious to find a method for determining the probability of rolling certain dice combinations. I understand the probability of rolling three sixes and a five on four fair sided dice as $4!/(3!\cdot1!) \cdot (1/6^4)$. However I have been unable to take that method much farther. How would one calculate the probability of rolling only one 6 and at least one 5?  Meaning one six, one five, and then any combination of 1-5. All being dependent on having only one 6 and at least one 5. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: Pr(Only one six) = Pr(Only one six and at least one five) + Pr(Only one six and no fives)

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the probability of rolling a 6 on the first die, and at least one 5 on the remaining three dice. These two events are independent, so the probability is

P(first die is 6)P(at least one of remaining is 5)

The probability that the first die is 6 is 1/6. Next,

P(at least one of remaining is 5) = 1-P(none of remaining is 5)

Now, if we look at P(none of remaining is 5), then we have three dice, none of which are 5. But they aren't 6, either, since we want the probability that exactly one die is six. That leave four out of six original possibilities, or 2/3. So for three dice, it's (2/3)^3. So our total probability is

(1/6)(1-(2/3)^3)

But that's for the first die being a 6. There are four choices for which die is 6, so the total probability is

4(1/6)(1-(2/3)^3)

Answer (score 0):

I have a preference for the counting method, especially when the number of outcomes is relatively small.

$P(\text{one $6$ plus one $5$ or more}) = \frac{\text{number of ways to get one 6 and one 5 or more}}{6^4}$

The number of ways to get one 6 and one 5 or more = $^4P_2(^5P_2 + 5)$ where $^4P_2$ is the number of ways of getting a single $6$ and a single $5$ out of $4$ outcomes. $^5P_2$ is the number of ways for the other two outcomes to be from $1$ to $5$ but different numbers, and $+5$ for them being the same number. $6^4$ is the total number of outcomes.

$P(\text{one $6$ plus one $5$ or more}) = \frac{^4P_2(^5P_2 + 5)}{6^4} = \frac{12(20+5)}{6^4} = \frac{300}{1296} = .2315$